# tkinter grid geom - using percentages instead of number of rows and columns

Tags: tkinter

I am building a application using tkinter.  I have used a template created in excel to specify the number of columns and rows.

[image]

Besides  I have also set the `master.geometry` to always open the application to full screen.

```
master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()))
```

When I open the application in the machine that I have developed, it opens perfectly as designed in the example layout.  However, when I change the monitor and open, a portion of application on the right handsize of the screen goes outside the screen.

Is there a way where I can take the screen width and height and distribute the widgets to occupy space `proportionately` using percentage of space.

Comment: You do not need so many rows and columns. Instead you should lean to use a Frame ( or other widgets) as a master to host other slave widgets. I recommend you study some tkinter tutorials on using `.grid()` to position widgets. Try this [example](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html).

Comment: If grid layout manager is used, you can use `rowconfigure(row, weight=n)` and `columnconfigure(col, weight=n)` to layout frame size by ratio.  For example, `master.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)` and `master.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` will make column 0 occupy around 67% of available space and column 1 occupy around 33% of available space.

Comment: @acw1668 That is not completely right. You also need to give them the same uniform-tag. So: ```master.columnconfigure(0,weight=2,uniform='tag')``` and ```master.columnconfigure(1,weight=1,uniform='tag')```. :)